# Importing Qt Quick Application project in QtCreator

Tags: qt, import, qt-creator, qt-quick

I'm trying to import a Qt Quick-Application project from a colleague of mine into my QtCreator installation. Both QtCreator versions are exactly the same.

When I am opening the .pro file I get the message that the .user file could not be found, although it is in the same folder.

When I click on proceed I am getting a default project imported but not all the files of the project which are present and should be recognized.

Also trying to add the remaining data through the option from the right-mouse-click menu does not have any effect.

Anyone here to give me a hint?

Comment: as to the first point, did you try removing the .pro.user file? that should be recreated automatically if not present, and it is specific to your local settings

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Marco! That made me configure the project with a new kit but didn't solve my actual problem...
What did the trick was changing the paths in the old .user file.

Comment: Glad you solved it. However, the .user file is meant to be developer and platform specific and should not be checked into version control. Take a look here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/6133/crossplatform-pro-user-project-file/12 That code probably needs some refactoring.